# Rails 3.2 + Searchkick + Mongoid : Getting Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound even after reindexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongoid

Even after reindexing the model / entire application i am getting Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound while executing search. Any pointers?

Comment: we need more information (model, complete log error...)

Comment: it got fixed when i rebooted the system.....